# Indexing lines of a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find a way to index the lines of a text file.

I use the following code to read the txt data

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    lines=f.read()
    print(lines)`
```

the result is

```
Aberdeen, Scotland
Adelaide, Australia
Algiers, Algeria
```

but I would like to put `1:`,`2:`,`3:` in front of each line.So I suppose that I have to do something like the following

```
with open('file.txt','a') as  f:
    for i in len(f):
        line='i:'+(ith line of txt file)
        f.write(line)
```

but I have a hard time solving it, any help will be great.

Comment: Im going to check it out

Answer (score 0):

You must handle two files, one for the input and one for the output:

```
with open("file.txt") as finp, open("newfile.txt","w") as fout:
  for index,line in enumerate(finp):
    fout.write(str(index)+": "+line)
```

If you want to start numbering from 1, write:   enumerate(finp,1)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two handle files. Just use seek.

```
file_path = "file.txt"

with open(file_path,"r+") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.seek(0)
    for index,line in enumerate(lines):
        to_write_string = str(index)+': '+line
        file.write(to_write_string)
```

This should do the trick..